# How to load url in Android's WebView to look properly?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-webview

I am loading `http://www.google.com` url in the the WebView.
But, even though I am loading it from the device/simulator, the content of the webview is not getting adjusted based on the device dimensions.

[image: Screen shot of the image]

If you see, Google page is not getting set properly according to the dimensions of the WebVie. But, if I open the same url in the simulator browser with same dimensions, then its loading properly with scaling etc.

How to make a webview load properly on a WebView in Android?

Here is the XML of the WebView Layout
`<WebView android:id="@+id/webView1" android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="300dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_below="@+id/button1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />`

MainActivity.java file

`WebView web_view =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1); web_view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); web_view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); web_view.loadUrl("google.com";);`

Comment: Can we see the XML of your layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the user-agent to make it not load mobile sites.

---

Try this

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_below="@+id/button1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: @Daniel.. I dont want to use the complete screen. If I open the same in url in the simulator browser, then the mobile version of the url is getting loaded. But, in case of webview, why this is not happening?